# Hair won't bend in a specific direction as if something is blocking it

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, rigging, particles, hair

I've been trying to comb a hair on a model with no luck so far. I just did this yesterday on 2 other models where everything worked fine. This time when I try to comb the hair particles, it won't straighten and starts to deform into curly curves, as if something is blocking it in the air. This happens on some strands only but it is enough to ruin my character completely.
[image: Curled hair for no reason]

I first thought it's maybe because of hair dynamics and collision but 
1.) there is no collision on the body 
2.) this happens with hair dynamics turned off. And when I deleted the body, rig etc (everything), the hair still curled this way.

In fact, hair dynamics is the only saviour as if I wait and let the hair fall down, it will straighten but this isn't a viable solution.

[image]

Second try
[image]
Same method and settings are working on another model

Comment: I encountered the same problem.. did you managed to find a solution or the cause of error?

Answer (score 1):

After i posted the comment i found the solution..

In particle edit mode press n for the sidebar and in the tool panel is the deflect emitter checkbox.

Uncheck that and you can do what you want with the hair.

Comment: i had a hair that i couldn't comb downwards as if there was a transparent plane in its way. this got fixed by this as well, thaaaanks!!! it was driving me nuts, it was only in the front, everywhere else I could manage the hair, finally :D

Comment: Glad i could help you.